# Android and Windows 7 Homegroup

Tags: networking, windows

I have an Android tablet and my PC running Windows 7 Pro. I am using ES File Explorer on Android to see shared folders.

I added some folders to the Music/Picture/Video libraries and shared them in a homegroup. I tried to make the homegroup not need a password and it'll let me access my PC from my tablet and view the root folders but as soon as I tried to access a folder (Music) it'll say permissions aren't available. It will work if I set a password and login with my account.

The second issue is that I'm seeing folders that I don't want to see. I can see a ADMIN$ folder (which is C:\WINDOWS), C$, D$, E$ (the HDDs), IPC$, print$, User. As well as Music, Pictures, Videos from the library. The folders in bold aren't shared so I don't know why I'm seeing them.

The last issue is that a folder (a whole drive actually) isn't being shared. I included the whole E: Drive in the Videos folder but it won't show up in the Video folder from the tablet. However if I include a folder from within the E: Drive then it will show up. Can I not include the root of a drive in a library? I mean it works on the PC.